# amazon connect CCP is try to connect to awsapps.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

We tried to use a custom Contact Control Panel (CCP). It tries to connect to `awsapp.com` but throws `x-frame-options error`. How to disable that?

Function:

```
connect.core.initCCP(containerDiv, {
            ccpUrl: instanceURL,            // REQUIRED
            loginPopup: false,               // optional, defaults to `true`
            loginPopupAutoClose: true,      // optional, defaults to `false`
            loginOptions: {                 // optional, if provided opens login in new window
                autoClose: true,              // optional, defaults to `false`
                height: 600,                  // optional, defaults to 578
                width: 400,                   // optional, defaults to 433
                top: 0,                       // optional, defaults to 0
                left: 0                       // optional, defaults to 0
            },
            region: "us-east-1",         // REQUIRED for `CHAT`, optional otherwise
            softphone: {                    // optional, defaults below apply if not provided
                allowFramedSoftphone: true,   // optional, defaults to false
                disableRingtone: false,       // optional, defaults to false
                ringtoneUrl: "./ringtone.mp3" // optional, defaults to CCP’s default ringtone if a falsy value is set
            },
            pageOptions: { //optional
                enableAudioDeviceSettings: true, //optional, defaults to 'false'
                enablePhoneTypeSettings: true //optional, defaults to 'true' 
            },
            shouldAddNamespaceToLogs: false, //optional, defaults to 'false'
            ccpAckTimeout: 5000, //optional, defaults to 3000 (ms)
            ccpSynTimeout: 3000, //optional, defaults to 1000 (ms)
            ccpLoadTimeout: 10000 //optional, defaults to 5000 (ms)
        });
```

Getting this error:

> Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
> chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1 Refused to display 'https://xx.awsapps.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Am not using `awsapps.com`. Do I have to?

I tried to disable the `x-frame` using plugin. It worked, however I don't want to use `awsapps.com`!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your CCP url as an Approved Origin in the AWS console.

You can read more about it in the admin guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/app-integration.html

The awspapps.com comes from your instances url. Your instance url should be something like instance-name.awsapp.com. Maybe you are using instance-name.my.connect.com, but this also forwards to instance-name.awsapp.com.